# Using the Nelder-Mead algorithm to find a maximum

Tags: optimization

In the Nelder-Mead algorithm, the simplex looks for the minimum of the function. If I multiply all the function values times -1, would I trick the simplex into searching for the maximum?

Comment: Yes, $\min_x f(x) = -\max_x -f(x)$, independent of the method used to compute it.

Comment: @ChristianClason: This means that we can use minimization algorthims to find maxima and maximization algorithm to find minima always?

Comment: Exactly. This is why textbooks usually talk about just one of the two.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, any minimization method can be used to find a maximum by applying it to
$$ -\min_{x} -f(x) = \max_{x} f(x) $$
(with the usual caveats that such a maximum must exist and $-f$ needs to have the required properties for the minimization method to work).